# Handle commas in quoted strings in Tcl

Tags: regex, csv, tcl

I'm using the following line in Tcl to parse a comma-separated line of fields. Some of the fields may be quoted so they can contain comma's:

```
set line {12,"34","56"}
set fresult [regsub -all {(\")([^\"]+)(\",)|([^,\"]+),} $line {{\2\4} } fields]
puts $fields
{12} {34} "56"
```

(It's a bit strange that the last field is quoted instead of braced but that's not the problem here)

However, when there is a comma in the quote, it does not work:

```
set line {12,"34","56,78"}
set fresult [regsub -all {(\")([^\"]+)(\",)|([^,\"]+),} $line {{\2\4} } fields]
puts $fields
{12} {34} "{56} 78"
```

I would expect: 
{12} {34} {56,78}

Is there something wrong with my regexp or it there something tcl-ish going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option that comes to mind is using the CSV functionality in TclLib. (No reason to reinvent the wheel unless you have to...)

http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/csv.html

Docs Excerpt

> ::csv::split ? -alternate ? line
>   {sepChar ,} {delChar "} converts a
>   line in CSV format into a list of the
>   values contained in the line. The
>   character used to separate the values
>   from each other can be defined by the
>   caller, via sepChar, but this is
>   optional. The default is ",". The
>   quoting character can be defined by
>   the caller, but this is optional. The
>   default is '"'.  If the option
>   -alternate is spcified a slightly different syntax is used to parse the
>   input. This syntax is explained below,
>   in the section FORMAT.

Comment: Wow, that's what I call a useful utility library. I presume it is available on latest Tcl version (as of 8.5) when using 'package require csv' ?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately tcllib is not standard included in Tcl/Tk 8.5 . So I think this is the best solution, but if do not want this dependency, use my 2nd comment from Kobi's answer.

Comment: The csv lib in tcllib is just one or two scripts too, no C code, so you could just copy them if you don't want to install the whole package.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be an extra comma: you only accept quoted strings if they have a comma after them., and do the same for non-quoted tokens, This works:

```
set fresult [regsub -all {(\")([^\"]+)(\")|([^,\"]+)} $line {{\2\4} } fields]
                                        ^(no commas)^
```

Working Example: **http://ideone.com/O2hss**

You can safely keep the commas out of the pattern - the regex engine will keen searching new matches: it will skip a comma it cannot match, and start at the next character.

*Bonus:* this will also handle escaped quotes, using `\"` (if you need you should be able to adapt easily by using `""` instead of `\\.` ).:

```
set fresult [regsub -all {"((?:[^"\\]|\\.)+)"|([^,"]+)} $line {{\1\2} } fields]
```

Example: **http://ideone.com/ztkBh**

Comment: Thanks, the website ideone.com itself is very nice indeed!

Comment: I do need the comma's (otherwise I have to get rid of them), also because there might be empty fields. However, you put me on the right track. The following seems to work: set fresult [regsub -all {(\")([^\"]+)(\"),?|([^,\"]+),?|,} $line {{\2\4} } fields]

Comment: @Roalt - Thanks! It allows me to write TCL code, even thought I haven't the slightest idea what it is `:)`. Oh, and if it already has a CSV library, I'd go with that.

Comment: @Kobi - You don't know what you missed out on! In the 80s-90s Tcl was THE language to use to make user interfaces on unix machines ;-) (Oh, and it's Tcl or Tcl/Tk, not TCL, it's a iPhone kinda thing)

Comment: Ok, if you do not want to be dependable on tcllib, this is the best solution (note that I used the somewhat modified answer in my 2nd comment here).

Comment: @Roalt - no problem. You are right on both accounts - a CSV parser is better, and I forgot empty elements. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the following regsub

```
% set line {12,"34","56,78"}

% regsub -all {(,")|(",)|"} $line " " line

% set line

12 34  56,78  <<< Result
```

Here all the occurrences of `,"` or `",` or `"` (in order) are replaced by space

Comment: For this example it will work, but if you have quoted strings with spaces in it you cannot see the original separations.

Answer (score 0):

As you said to @Kobi, if you allow for empty fields, you should allow for empty strings ""
`{((\")([^\"]*)(\")|([^,\"]*))(,|$)}` where the fields of interest shifted to 3 and 5

Expanded:  `{ ( (\")([^\"]*)(\") | ([^,\"]*) ) (,|$) }` I admit, I don't know if tcl allows (?:) non-capture grouping.

Comment: Trying it always delivers a result where the last field is empty: e.g. set line 12 -> "{12} {}"